# Windows CE using VS 2013 & VB.Net

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-ce

I am using VB.net  &  Visual Studio 2013 , I like to write a Windows CE  application
After searching on the internet I installed VS Update 4, vsSdk, Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh, Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional Developer Tool Kit (USA), But nothing is working ,I still don't get the template I did a lot of reading  on this issue but I still don't know what do I need  to install or where to get it in order to write a VB.net  Windows CE  application ,
Thanks, Shay

Comment: I believe Visual Studio 2008 was the last version that supported Windows CE, Windows Mobile, and .Net Compact Framework.  I have not tried using VS 2013, but I do know that I could not setup VS 2010 for the last time I worked on that platform (about 3-4 years ago).  Also, I seem to remember I had to use Windows Vista for this, as Windows 7 did not support it either.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 can be used to develop applications for Windows Embedded 2013 only. All the other versions (Windows CE 6.0, Windows Embedded Compact, Windows Mobile, Windows Embedded Handheld) are supported only by Visual Studio 2008.
If your device provides the .NET runtime or if it allows you to install it (providing all the required OS components to do that), then you can use VB.NET as development language.